# Find the missing letter (Alphabet puzzle)

Tags: logical-deduction, sequence, letter-sequence

[image: Puzzle]

What letter replaces '?' in the stack? How do you arrive at it?

Source: CSIR NET December 2018 QP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's `Z`.

There are patterns which we need to see.

> E = 5, O = 15 so the difference is 10.
>  P = 16, so Z = 26.
>  G = 7, J = 10, the difference is 3.
>  R = 18, so adding 3 would be 21 which is U.
>  F = 6, K = 11, difference = 5. 
>  Q = 17, so adding 5 would be 22 which is V